# Laravel/Livewire Count not visible in blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Good afternoon. I have a count that seems to work but it's not visible in the blade.

In the Controller:

```
    public function render()
    {
        $projekte = Project::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10);
        $count = Project::withCount('games')
            ->get();

        //dd($count);

        return view('livewire.projects.project-overview', compact ('projekte','count'));
    }
```

in the blade

```
@foreach($projekte as $project)
<p>{{$project->games_count}} </p>
@endforeach
```

If I DD the $games I can see the correct amount.

[DD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miXOQ.png)

[Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfM4i.png)

I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: You probably want just `Project::orderBy('id','desc')->withCount('games')->paginate(10)`. The entire `$count = ...` line can go. `$projekte` doesn't know about `$count`, so the count won't be in your foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the verifiable "$count" and accessing the project variable in the view file.

You can act in this manner.

```php
$projekte = Project::withCount("games")->latest()->paginate(10);
```

After that, you can access the file in your view as follows.

```php
@foreach( $projekte as $project )
    <p>{{ $project->games_count }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Happy Coding!...

Answer (score 0):

The answer from ceejayoz was the correct one.
You probably want just `Project::orderBy('id','desc')->withCount('games')->paginate(10).` The entire `$count = ...` line can go. `$projekte` doesn't know about `$count`, so the count won't be in your foreach. –
ceejayoz
27 mins ago